# Missing openssl cipher-algorithms on specific VMs/Hoster

Tags: hardware, openssl, cipher

I'm trying to use AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256 but this cipher-algorithm isn't available on a VM on a specific hosting provider.

The OS, installed packages, Kernel, openssl version, and the like are the same on both VMs (different provider).

Does this have to do with specific CPU flags?

This is the diff of the `openssl list-cipher-algorithms` command run on 2 servers on different providers:

`@@ -1,4 +1,6 @@
 AES-128-CBC
+AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
+AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
 AES-128-CFB
 AES-128-CFB1
 AES-128-CFB8
@@ -14,6 +16,8 @@
 AES-192-ECB
 AES-192-OFB
 AES-256-CBC
+AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
+AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
 AES-256-CFB
 AES-256-CFB1
 AES-256-CFB8
@@ -102,6 +106,8 @@
 SEED-ECB
 SEED-OFB
 AES-128-CBC
+AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
+AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
 id-aes128-CCM
 AES-128-CFB
 AES-128-CFB1
@@ -121,6 +127,8 @@
 id-aes192-GCM
 AES-192-OFB
 AES-256-CBC
+AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA1
+AES-256-CBC-HMAC-SHA256
 id-aes256-CCM
 AES-256-CFB
 AES-256-CFB1`

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any hint about ciphers depending on specific hardware. Just that specific CPU capabilities speed up some algorithms.

Any hint on how I could use these cipher-algorithms would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure the kernels and everything are the same?  How did you check?  Simply looking at the version number is not enough.  Might need to compare checksums or something.

Comment: @Zoredache: All systems are set-up using the same operating system and versions. And yes, even the md5sum of both kernel images are identical. The OS is Amazon linux 2 and the kernel version used is 4.14.128-112.105.amzn2.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue, AES-128-CBC-HMAC-SHA256 was missing on one VM but available on other VM running same OS with same kernel. I had to vmotion VM off to ESXi running on AMD Opteron 6380 which supports aes flag.

`#grep -m1 -o aes /proc/cpuinfo
aes`

Comment: That's exactly what I thought but I couldn't find any prove for that. Thanks!